# Change img url on all images via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of images, with this kind of structure:

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="p" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Product">
        <a href="/head/" class="p-image">
            <img src="https://cdn.myshoptet.com/usr/www.nebenebo.cz/user/shop/detail/348.jpg?5a1af136" data-src="https://cdn.myshoptet.com/usr/www.nebenebo.cz/user/shop/detail/348.jpg?5a1af136" alt="69Jirka Macek Head">
            <meta itemprop="image" content="https://cdn.myshoptet.com/usr/www.nebenebo.cz/user/shop/big/348.jpg?5a1af136">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using JS, I need to change the path folder from `"detail/"` to `"big/"` on all img's with the particular class.

I tried this, but it's not working:

```
$('.product a img').attr('src').replace('detail', 'big');
```

Comment: I try this, but not working, here is my site www.nebenebo.cz

Comment: @SnipermMan, you have my working snippet

Comment: This is not working for me :-( i change "replaceThis" to "detail" and "withThis" to "big" ...

Answer (score 0):

```js
//if you want to change the "detail" to "big" for all images, 
$('.product a img').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('detail', 'big'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
<div class="p" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Product">
<a href="/head/" class="p-image">
<img src="https://cdn.myshoptet.com/usr/www.nebenebo.cz/user/shop/detail/348.jpg?5a1af136" data-src="https://cdn.myshoptet.com/usr/www.nebenebo.cz/user/shop/detail/348.jpg?5a1af136" alt="69Jirka Macek Head">
                    <meta itemprop="image" content="https://cdn.myshoptet.com/usr/www.nebenebo.cz/user/shop/big/348.jpg?5a1af136">
    </a>   
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: @SnipermMan You mean, not or now. Are you sure that your html is loading your jquery code ?

Comment: sorry, not ... look at www.nebenebo.cz

Comment: @SnipermMan Are you sure that your html is loading your jquery code ? Could you do `console.log(initial) ` of my code and put it here?

Comment: Yes, look to code of site, your code is on 5528 row.

Comment: <script>
//get initial url
var initial = $('.product a img').attr('src');
//replace detail by big
initial = initial.replace('detail', 'big')
//set the new url after replacing "detail" by "big"
$('.product a img').attr('src', initial)
</script>

Comment: @SnipermMan, you have several images that are selected with jquery. Would you like to change `detail` into `big` for all of them ?

Comment: yes of all images of this category on this page ... with folder big have image big dimensions ... can you try

Comment: which code? ... sorry ... too many codes .. to many comments ... thx

Comment: @SnipermMan, you can have a look at it

Comment: I add this code

<script>
$('.product a img').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('detail', 'big'));
</script>

but not working

Comment: When you say, not working, what do you mean exactly, that your image is not big?

Comment: Images are not clear, becouse are small. Ineed change path of this images to /big/ folder where is big images.

Comment: The code changes the images to use the one in `big` folder, I checked that on the website. But if the image is still small, it is a matter of how the CSS is applied on the page.

Comment: Look to first product (Love is all):
Image have this src:
https://cdn.myshoptet.com/usr/www.nebenebo.cz/user/shop/detail/300.jpg?59c7ece8

But i need this:
https://cdn.myshoptet.com/usr/www.nebenebo.cz/user/shop/big/300.jpg?59c7ece8

Can try and change via firebug and look on image is -> better, clear, becouse is bigger.